# connect app to php server on localhost

Tags: php, android, localhost

how can i connect an android app (on my phone) to a php server (EasyPHP) that i am running on my machine (localhost). Are there any tutorials out there that document this.
I need to test the app on an actual phone not an emulator (because the emulator contains bugs for certain activities). Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect on your Android with WiFi, you will be in the same network, then you can access PHP server via your machine's IP address.

Comment: Server should be visible in public network - it has to have public IP.

Answer (score 0):

Ys you connect to the php script...

Android allows you to sent data in GET and POST method..
I found a useful tutorials about this: [Android phpMysql connection](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/android-phpmysql-connection/)